# PHP FATAL causing '500' server error

Tags: php

I have a remotely hosted site running 'The Next Generation' genealogical software => LAMP.

I regularly download the complete site and install in on my 'localhost' as both a backup and a test bench for testing upgrades etc.

Have been doing this for perhaps 5 yrs without issue .. however, over the past week i have built a new server using Mint 14.1 and have followed the same historic procedures to transfer the remote site internally ... however, i keep getting a '500 - server error' which is caused by a FATAL PHP issue, according to the the apache2 logs.

```
PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function session_register() in /home/griadooss/www/genetracer.net/globallib.php on line 5
```

line 5 in the said 'globallib.php' file contains;

```
1 <?php
2 @ini_set( "session.bug_compat_warn", "0" );
3 @ini_set( "allow_url_fopen", "0" );
4 session_start();
5 session_register('session_language');
6 session_register('session_charset');
7 $session_language = $_SESSION[session_language];
8 $session_charset = $_SESSION[session_charset];
9 session_register('assignedtree');
.
.
.
```

Apache2, mySql and php are the latest as provided by their repositories .. installed via the apt-get call without issue. Database is fine ... phpMyAdmin connects without issue. Database type = MyISAM; collation = latin1_swedish_ci. The single anomaly that arises is this '500' error

I have no ideas of where to go from here .. i have reinstalled the system from scratch three times with the same result ... would be most grateful if somebody could help me out.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

That's happening because you have now a newer version of php.

Check [this php documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-register.php). It says that the function you are trying to use is no longer supported on php 5.4++.

Thanks!

@leo